# How to convert multiple SQL joins to LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have been working on an issue for some time now and have managed to come up with the SQL code required. I am currently using .NET Core 2.0 and am trying to write the following in LINQ using a db context.

Here is what I've tried so far, but with no luck (I was trying to get a minimal example working):

```
 from s in _context.Table1
 join f in _configContext.Table2 on s.Id.ToString() equals f.Id
 select s;
```

Comment: Are the casts really needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do `LEFT JOIN` in LINQ, you need `DefaultIfEmpty()`.

The attached code is the concept of performing `LEFT JOIN` tables in LINQ way as requested.

```
var result = (
        from a in _contextA.Table1
        join b in _contextB.Table2 on a.Id.ToString() equals b.Id into ab
        from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join c in _contextC.Table3 on a.Id equals c.Id into ac
        from c in ac.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join d in _contextD.Table4 on a.Id equals d.Id into ad
        from d in ad.DefaultIfEmpty() 
        select new { a.Id, Name = b.Name + " " + c.Name + " " + d.Name }
        )
        .ToList();
```

Note:

1. You may switch the `Id` field to string for comparison only when it is needed.
2. Replace `_contextA`, `_contextB`, `_contextC`, `_contextD` to your real context for respective `Table1`, `Table2`, `Table3`, `Table4`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add the nuget package [linq2db](https://dotnetfoundation.org/projects/linq2db). This package is a LINQ database access library and gives you a lot of more flexibility when creating LINQ queries. With that package you can create your query as follows:

```
using LinqToDb;

var query = from t1 in _context.Table1
            from t2 in _context.Table2.LeftJoin(x => x.Id.ToString() == t1.Id.ToString()) 
            from t3 in _context.Table3.LeftJoin(x => x.Id.ToString() == t1.Id.ToString())
            from t4 in _context.Table3.LeftJoin(x => x.Id.ToString() == t1.Id.ToString()) 
            select new 
            {
              t1Id = t1.Id,
              concatNames = $"{t2.Name}{t3.Name}{t4.Name}"
            };
```

As you can see, its pretty straightforward. An alternative, if you only need more LINQ methods, is the package [morelinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ). This one has even more operations (as far as I know), but im not too familiar with it tbh.